# Asp.Net - Write True/False on UI based on boolean value of checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, boolean-operations

I am working on this form in VS2012 and SQL Server 2008R2. The table gets the bit value of true or false. In the Gridview itemtemplate, instead of displaying the empty checkbox I want to say "True or False". How can I do that? This is what I have done so far:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# (Eval("Banned").ToString())%>' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Text` property of the `CheckBox` control, like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
              Checked='<%# DisplayTruth(Eval("Banned").ToString()) %>'
              Text='<%# DisplayTruthValue(Eval("Banned").ToString()) %>' />
```

Now in your code-behind, create the two methods, like this:

```
protected bool DisplayTruth(string banned)
{
    if(banned == "0")
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

protected string DisplayTruthValue(string banned)
{
    if(banned == "0")
    {
        return "True";
    }

    return "False";
}
```

I recommend this approach for the following reasons:

- The markup does not contain conditional/ternary logic
- It is easier to debug the logic versus embedded code blocks
- You can leverage the power of Visual Studio compiler to catch syntax errors at compile-time versus run-time errors when the logic is embedded into the binding syntax of the markup

Comment: Thanks Karl, you answered my question. I changed this to vb and it is working fine. As you mentioned I can use the text what I want to display.

Comment: @Nita - glad it helped, I was guessing you wanted C#. Feel free to edit the answer to include the VB.NET version or I can do it if you want.

Comment: @Nita - if you feel this answer helped you, then please accept the answer and/or up-vote the answer. :-)

Comment: I did vote for the answer, I did not know I was supposed to do it. Voting means accepting the answer?

Comment: @Nita - no you are not required to accept the answer, nor up-vote it. You only up-vote if you think the answer is useful to you or others, you accept the answer if you feel it was the answer that best solves your problem. Generally, if you accept an answer you also up-vote the answer, as a solution is usually also helpful. You get to decide that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found this information and it is working. Also I changed asp:checkbox to asp:label. However I want to display "No" instead of "False" so I changed "False" to "No" but still my app says "False".

```
<asp:Label ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# IIf(Convert.ToString(Eval("Banned")) = "", "No", Eval("Banned"))%>' />
```